# How to write IAM policy to check list for multiple possible values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an IAM policy that uses a combination of tag-based authorization (tag-1 & tag-2) as well as ARN name matching for S3 actions.
I currently have to write 3 separate resources (prod, nonprod, and dev). Is there a way to create a list to have IAM check a list of acceptable values that I create in the policy instead of having to rewrite the same line every time a new possible environment is created (i.e. dev, test, etc.)?

```
{
    "Action": ["s3:*"],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::${aws:PrincipalTag/tag-1}-${aws:PrincipalTag/tag-2}-prod-*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::${aws:PrincipalTag/tag-1}-${aws:PrincipalTag/tag-2}-nonprod-*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::${aws:PrincipalTag/tag-1}-${aws:PrincipalTag/tag-2}-dev-*"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Sid": "AllowLimitedS3AccessBasedOnArnMatching"
}
```

Comment: No that is not possible according to IAM policy grammar - `<resource_block> = ("Resource" | "NotResource") : 
    ("*" | [<resource_string>, <resource_string>, ...])`

Comment: I see... it's just funny that they allow wildcards/tags and other 'variables' to be used but not something like a list to check against

Comment: What information do you store in `PrincipalTag`? If it is a user identifier, take a look at: [IAM Policy Elements: Variables and Tags - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html)